# if $s=\sum_{k=1}^n x_k $ , $x_k>0$ how to show that $n (\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{x_k}{s-x_k})^{-1}\leq n-1$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series, inequality, cauchy-schwarz-inequality

this question is from W. J. Kaczor and M. T. Nowak, Problems in Mathematical Analysis I. Real Numbers, Sequences and Series

> if $s=\sum_{k=1}^n x_k $ , $ x_k>0$ I want to show that $n (\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{x_k}{s-x_k})^{-1}\leq n-1$

my method was as the arithmetic mean ≥ harmonic mean then
$$n (\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{x_k}{s-x_k})^{-1} ≤\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{s-x_k}{x_k}= \frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{s}{x_k} -1$$
so if I could prove that $\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{s}{x_k}<n$ then I could get the result
but applying the arithmetic mean ≥ harmonic mean , then $\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{s}{x_k}>n$ which lead to nothing and here I got stuck.

Comment: Applying the arithmetic-harmonic inequality on the problem itself is hard. Try applying it to $n \left( \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{s-x_k} \right)^{-1}$ first.

Comment: Also the inequality for the problem should be “$\leq$” not just “$<$”. That is because if $x_k=1$ for all $k \leq n$ then the strict inequality doesn’t hold.

Comment: $x\mapsto x/(s-x)$ is convex on $[0,s]$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For $n\geq2$ by C-S twice we obtain:
$$\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{x_k}{S-x_k}=\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{x_k^2}{Sx_k-x_k^2}\geq\frac{\left(\sum\limits_{k=1}^nx_k\right)^2}{\sum\limits_{cyc}(Sx_k-x_k^2)}=$$
$$=\frac{\left(\sum\limits_{k=1}^nx_k\right)^2}{\left(\sum\limits_{cyc}x_k\right)^2-\frac{1}{n}\sum\limits_{k=1}^n1^2\sum\limits_{k=1}^nx_k^2}\geq\frac{\left(\sum\limits_{k=1}^nx_k\right)^2}{\left(\sum\limits_{cyc}x_k\right)^2-\frac{1}{n}\left(\sum\limits_{k=1}^nx_k\right)^2}=\frac{n}{n-1}.$$